# How to install AWX successfully with docker-compose if reinstall it again?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ansible, host, ansible-awx

The first time installed it succeeded. But reinstall it again, always failed.

---

Use docker-compose install AWX

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory install.yml
```

Error

```
TASK [local_docker : Start the containers] *******************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "errors": [], "module_stderr": "Creating awx_postgres ... \nCreating awx_memcached ... \nCreating awx_redis     ... \n\u001b[2A\u001b[2K\nCreating awx_memcached ... \n\u001b[2B\u001b[3A\u001b[2K\nCreating awx_postgres  ... \n\u001b[3B\u001b[1A\u001b[2K\nCreating awx_redis     ... \n\u001b[1BCreating awx_web       ... \nHost is already in use by another container\n\u001b[1A\u001b[2K\nCreating awx_web       ... \n\u001b[1B", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "Error starting project Encountered errors while bringing up the project."}
```

I deleted all the posible resources

```
cd ~/.awx/awxcompose
docker-compose down

docker network prune
docker volume prune
docker container prune
docker image prune
```

Install it again still got the same error.

Comment: Error is "Host is already in use by another container". Seems you have another containers running there. Run docker ps to list them and docker rm -f if you want to remove them.

Comment: Yes, host was used by another port. Delete it works.

Comment: Added it as answer. Accept it please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List all running containers and find yours

```
Docker ps
```

Remove it

```
Docker rm -f container_id
```

Start it again (docker run ..., or use your docker-compose)